# How to send private message to my contacts using PHP Facebook SDK?

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm developing app that sends message to friends with Facebook.
I found many solution on stackoverflow but those answers are not working(already deprecated in facebook.)

Could anyone please tell me how to send message using Facebook api?
Thanks.

Comment: The Send dialog allows you to let users send a link to friends - but they have to select the recipients themselves, and actively trigger it. This is nothing you can do programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to send messages using the API. You can only send messages to users as page, and users would need to initiate the conversation.

Comment: Is there no way to send private message?

Comment: I repeat from my answer: "There is no way"

Comment: and honestly, there is no use case where this would make sense. just use facebook.com and the official messenger.